# PortAudio-19 for mac

Tags: macos, pyaudio

My issue is want to install portaudio-19 on mac.

The following doesnt get installed with help of brew

```
sudo brew install portaudio19-dev
```

How can I install portaudio using brew

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

There's a `portaudio` package in brew though, so this

```
brew install portaudio
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think brew has such a formula. You should build it from source.